# Lotus Notes: remove section from current form

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a userform in Lotus Notes with three sections: section1, section2 and section3.

The form is used by three employees: emp1, emp2, emp3. Of course there is no real employees ID's but it doesn't matter right now.

And the issue is: before of after opening the form (or right before save it) by emp1 the section2 and section3 must be completely removed from the form (not hided but removed). In case of emp2, removed must by section1 and section3.

Please help me with the question: is it possible to definitely remove section, field or button from the current form by lotus script code.

Comment: This sounds a bit backwards. Why isn't the Hide-When formula of sections an alternative? If you want to have one form, but a different set of fields based on user identity [Computed subforms](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CEMQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpublib.boulder.ibm.com%2Finfocenter%2Fdomhelp%2Fv8r0%2Ftopic%2Fcom.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc%2FH_ABOUT_SUBFORMS.html&ei=K76EUs7zH-W04ASPhIDwDQ&usg=AFQjCNGAa9k2f0d_AB5SPV_cQVSd2Bo9kw&sig2=fuP-xSkW-fCiGMemE_IV4A&bvm=bv.56343320,d.bGE&cad=rja) might be what you want.

Comment: The reason is very simply. Each section will contain a lot of attachements (I think that a large of all the attachements on every section will be about 1MB) and because of that each document created using the form will be a very large (important note: to simplify my issue description I wrote about 3 sections, in facts there will be 10-12 sections). When every user will be interested with only one section other sections (and of course other attachements) will be completely unnecessary. The target of removing unused sections is to reduce the large of the saved documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the sections in subforms and place the subforms to form as computed subforms. This way only the section(s) that you want will be on form.

Comment: I just noticed @AndersLindahl already suggested this. If you add your suggestion as an answer I will remove this one.

Answer (score 0):

All this should be possible using DXL and LotusScript (in fact we have done this before). But it is not a simple and easy process and I dare to ask if it is really necessary to let people firstly add attachments to a document, only to programmatically remove them afterwards. Would'nt it be  a better solution to store attachemnts into separate child documents, visible in the appropriate sections? That way you would keep the document small by still having all attachments. And it would allow you to add more control over what is readable for whom.